# Как передать изображение из HTML формы на FTP-сервер?

Tags: php, ftp-сервер

Есть форма, куда пользователь может добавить изображение, надо чтобы оно сохранялось на FTP-сервер. На всех сайтах один и тот же пример, на базе которого создан вот такой вот код...

```php
$filep = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$ftp_server = 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx';
$ftp_user_name = 'admin';
$ftp_user_pass = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$paths = "/АРХИВ/".$filep;
$name = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
  echo "Соединение не установлено!";
  echo "Попытка подключения $ftp_server для пользователя: $ftp_user_name";
  exit;
} else {
  echo "Соединение установлено $ftp_server для пользователя: $ftp_user_name";
}
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $paths.
  '/'.$name, $filep, FTP_BINARY);
if (!$upload) {
  echo "Загрузка не выполнена!";
} else {
  echo "Выполнена загрузка $name на $ftp_server";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
set_time_limit(300);
```

В итоге на сервере ничего нет) проблема в коде? Или что-то в настройках самого FTP-сервера надо поменять? К сожалению в сети на эту тему примеры трудно найти...

Comment: Какие сообщения выводятся? Какие ошибки возникают?

Comment: "Соединение установлено, загрузка не выполнена"

Comment: Проверьте или на сервере разрешено сохранять файл, то есть в свойствах директории куда вы сохраняете файл разрешена запись.

Comment: @hidden Попробуйте перед загрузкой добавить `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true)`. И еще попробуйте заменить `ftp_put` на `ftp_raw` и посмотреть, что реально возвращает сервер

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk запись разрешена в директорию, под данным аккаунтом также права на запись установлены... через Filezilla добавляются файлы нормально...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $paths. '/'.$name, $filep, FTP_BINARY);
```

где

```
$paths = "/АРХИВ/".$filep;
```

у вас всё пишется в католог `АРХИВ` от корня.

попробуйте хотя бы так:
  `$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $paths. '/'.$name, $filep, FTP_BINARY);`

Comment: Да, накосячила с директориями и именами файлов, поменяла `$paths = "/АРХИВ/".$filep;` на `$paths = "/АРХИВ/".$name;`. Изменила строку `$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $paths, $filep, FTP_BINARY);` и все стало работать. Спасибо!

Comment: @hidden, не за что, обращайтесь :)